# Weather update problem

Tags: weather

I use 9s-weather app. Its beautiful. But i can't set it up to update weather via 3G or WIFI. Its always want to activate the GPS.

Is it possible to update it without GPS?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It wants to know your location so that it can give you weather forecasts for where you are rather than some other random location.  It's just your location that comes from GPS - the weather info will be downloaded via wifi or your data network.

The app has permission to use both Android's coarse-grained (network-based) and fine (GPS) location services.  In your case, it seems that the app is failing to find your location using the network-based service (by seeing which cell-towers and wifi hotspots it can see) and falling back to GPS.